# How get full path with a http:// for a SRC image?

Tags: php, parsing, dom, domdocument

I have a function, that get all images from page:

```
function getImages(){
    $imageTags = $this->doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

    if(!empty($imageTags)){
        foreach($imageTags as $tag) {
            $this->result['images'][] = $tag->getAttribute('src');
        }
    }
}
```

In result array there are a SRC images with a relative or absolute path.
For example: `/images/1.jpg, images/2.jpg`

How I can get full path for each images?
For exmaple I need:

```
`http://web.com/images/1.jpg, http://web.com/images/2.jpg`
```

Comment: Use http://www.php.net/parse_url and check for the hostname. If not available, apply the same function to the page URL, extract hostname from there and append to your string.

Comment: It's not simple, but have a look at how [Symfony::DomCrawler::Link::getUri](https://github.com/symfony/DomCrawler/blob/master/Link.php#L89) converts URLs from href attributes to their absolute form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally if you are not receiving the full url the url will be the same as that which you scraped the image from.  So I would check for 'http', and if it is not found add to the image url all the text in the url which is before the first '/' after '.'.